# I am getting: TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object, but I am returning a tuple

Tags: python

I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
```

When I call this function:

```py
        # current client's schedule (dict)
        clientSchedule = client

        # value to let the program know if scheduling is 'finished'
        t1_processDone = False

        # the function itself, variable types are as follows:
        # client_name is a string, client_ID is an int,
        # client_team is a list, clientSchedule is a dict,
        # t1_processStatus is dynamically typed (True, False or None)
        clientSchedule, t1_processDone = insert_t1(client_name, client_ID,
                              client_team, clientSchedule, 
                              t1_processStatus)
```

The error occurs on this line:

```py
clientSchedule, t1_processDone = insert_t1(client_name, client_ID...)
```

`client_sch` is a dictionary that is not empty. From my research I see that this error occurs when a function returns `None`, and that value cannot be iterated over. But in this case I am expecting and returning a tuple.

Comment: where in your code `client_sch`is instanced?

Comment: client_sch is first instanced in main.py, it is passed into the the insert_t1() function as a dict with placeholder values. It gets updated and changed by insert_t1() and then returned to main.py with it's new values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can't be getting the error you say when executing the line:

```
return client_sch, True
```

because that line is not doing any unpacking.  If you mean that you are getting the error on the last line of your code when `insert_t1` returns via that line, that makes more sense.  But if that's true, then you shouldn't be getting the error you're getting.  This code runs fine:

```
def insert_t1(a, b, c, d, e):
    client_sch = None
    return client_sch, True

def main():

    client = ""
    client_name = ""
    client_ID = ""
    client_team = ""
    t1_processStatus = ""

    # current client's schedule (dict)
    clientSchedule = client

    # value to let the program know if scheduling is 'finished'
    t1_processDone = False

    # the function itself, variable types are as follows:
    # client_name is a string, client_ID is an int,
    # client_team is a list, clientSchedule is a dict,
    # t1_processStatus is dynamically typed (True, False or None)
    clientSchedule, t1_processDone = insert_t1(client_name, client_ID,
                                               client_team, clientSchedule,
                                               t1_processStatus)

main()
```

Note that this works even if `client_sch` is `None`. On the other hand, if your `insert_t1` function WAS returning `None`, you'd get the error you're seeing.  Just replace `return client_sch, True` with `return None` in the above code, and you get exactly the error you report.

So I'm guessing that what you present here somehow doesn't match up with the reality of your situation.  If you haven't already, I'd suggest looking for other ways that `insert_t1` can return, and maybe run your code in a debugger.  If you are getting the error you're getting given what you say, then the code I supply should also give you that error.  If it does, then there's something strange going on.  If it doesn't, then there's obviously something going on that is not visible in what you've provided.

Comment: Regarding your "first of all", good point, ill edit the question to reflect this.
Thanks for answering, your suggestions helped me find the issue. A simple goof by me.
Do you know why there are so many down-votes on my question? What was wrong with it? Id like to improve in the future.

Comment: My guess is that it is because you posted so little of your code. Ideally, you should post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that those reading your posts can duplicate the result you're getting.  More importantly, I think, it shows you respect this community enough to put together a complete presentation of your problem.  Sometimes in doing that, you find the problem yourself. Obviously, I thought your question was formed well enough that I could help you.  I'll upvote it to get rid of one of the downvotes.

Comment: I appreciate the advice, and the upvote, I will craft my next question with more care.

Comment: cool!  as long as you're conscious of it, you'll be fine.  This is a great place for new programmers and veterans alike to save a LOT of time